# Javascript back-link code inside PHP IF condition

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following Javascript code for (browser) Back-link URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event)
    {
        window.location.assign("https://backlink.com");
    });
</script>
```

And I would like to put it inside:

```
<?php
if( strpos( $source, 'abc' ) !== false ) {
    Javascript code should go here
}
?>
```

I tried it in different ways but always got Syntax error.
Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem ? just do `<?php
if( strpos( $source, 'abc' ) !== false ) {
?><script type="text/javascript">
history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
window.location.assign("https://backlink.com");
});
</script><?php
}
?>`

Comment: as a note: It's a bad idea to mix PHP + JS - they're executed differently and thus, it can lead to some unexpected behaviour. Much better (in this case) to use the DOM to create an element if `strpos !== false`. If this script is run on the server and isn't used for page creation, then it would be better to use AJAX

Comment: Which **exact** ways have you tried? Please share the attempts and the error messages

Comment: What got a syntax error? PHP or js?

Comment: Do you want the value of _<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];_ to be pushed into history?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments doing something like this is generally considered a bad idea but this should accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
if( strpos( $source, 'abc' ) !== false ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, null, "' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '"
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event)
    {
        window.location.assign("https://backlink.com");
    });
</script>}';
}
```

Comment: How is this any better though?